# how to send value from controller to my loader in core directory in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

in my current project i have divided header and footer from content part and made two view header and footer . and i am loading this view by a loader located in application/core folder . but i have to make  my menu dynamically from database value to header . now i am stuck and unable to think how can i do it . 
all i need is when someone click on the menu then with the url i want to show the content of that page from database by my controller.

can i send value to the header on the loader or i have to do it different way any suggestion
would be helpful . thanks advanced !

this is the loader file located in the application/core folder.

```
  <?php
    class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
      public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
      {
        if ($return) :
          $content  = $this->view('header', $vars, $return);
          $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
          $content .= $this->view('footer', $vars, $return);

          return $content;
        else:
          $this->view('header', $vars);
          $this->view($template_name, $vars);
          $this->view('footer', $vars);
        endif;
     }
   }
```

and this is my controller

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Indexcontroller extends CI_Controller
     {

        function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('showPage_model');
       }
      public function index()
      {
        $SendData = '';
        if(!$this->uri->segment(3)){}else
        {
           $page_no = $this->uri->segment(3);
           $search_result = $this->db->select('a.*')
                                ->from('menu_table as a')
                                ->where('a.MENU_ID',$page_no)
                                ->get();
          $result = $search_result->result();
          $SendData['page_content'] = $search_result->result();

        }
       $this->load->template('index.php',$SendData);
     }

   }
```

Comment: You can send variables with `$this->load->vars($SendData)` before loading pages. [Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars).

Comment: where to write the code you suggested ? i mean in controller or in loader ? if in controller then its not working !

Comment: It should work in controller. People usually use template library for such a purpose. However you need to write `public function __construct(){parent::__construct();}` in `MY_Loader`.